# Pivot table with each column having the previous columns value deducted from it

Tags: qliksense

I have a pivot table with a dimension of 'companyname', column of 'month' and a measure of SUM(number_of_sales).

I want to change the measure expression so each column shows the number of sales minus the number of sales in the previous month, so sort if the opposite of a cumulative, the idea being to show how the number of sales per month has increased month on month.

How would i go about this, i'm not even sure where to begin?

Was thinking maybe something like

```
SUM(IF(column=column(1),number_of_sales,IF(Column()=column(2),
```

But im having no luck.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Above function:

```
SUM(number_of_sales) - (Above(Sum(number_of_sales),1,1)).
```